# triggers en oracle

Tags: oracle

Tengo que constuir un trigger que cuando se inserte un registro en la tabla detalle_venta, ingrese la comisión en la tabla comisión, tiene que calcular la comisión (comision*cantidad)*0.05, mi trigger compila, pero cuando inserto un registro en detalle_venta me dice que: table TIENDA.DETALLE_VENTA is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER inserta_comision
    AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE 
    ON detalle_venta
    FOR EACH ROW 

    DECLARE
    vprecio     producto.precio%type;

    BEGIN
    SELECT P.precio 
        INTO vprecio
        FROM detalle_venta D 
        JOIN producto P
        ON ( D.id_producto = P.id_producto );

    IF INSERTING THEN 
        INSERT INTO comision values ( :new.folio_venta, (vprecio*:new.cantidad)*.05, sysdate );

    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: es cierto. porque haces un select y no tomas los valores que estas recibiendo en el trigger?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

No puedes hacer referencia a `detalle_venta` en una query dentro de un trigger para esa misma tabla. Por eso recibes el error.

De todos modos, tu `SELECT` no tiene mucho sentido, y probablemente te daría otro error si pudiera correr, porque te devolvería demasiados registros.

Sin entender todo a 100%, lo más probable es que simplemente quieras eliminar la tabla `detalle_venta` de la consulta y mas bien usar directamente `:new.id_producto` en la consulta:

```
SELECT P.precio 
INTO vprecio
FROM producto P
WHERE P.id_producto = :new.id_producto;
```